Represent the hyperboloid model $I^n$ using Lie groups
Consider the hyperboloid model $I^n=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}|<x,x>=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i-x_{n+1}y_{n+1}=-1, x_{n+1}>0\}$.
I know that $S^2\cong SO(3)/SO(2).$ Now, similarly, I want to find one for $I^n$.
For simplicity, take $n=2$. Then we have $x^2+y^2-z^2=-1(z>0).$
The orientation-preserving isometry of $I^2$ is $SO(3)$ by the fact that
$$Isom(I^n)=O^{+}(n,1)=\{f\in GL(n+1,\mathbb{R}):\forall v,w\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}, <v,w>=<fv,fw>\}/\{\pm I\}$$
My idea is to choose a point $(0,0,1)=x\in I^3$ and find its stabilizer. It is easy to do in $S^2$ as the stabilizer of $(0,0,1)$ is just the rotation of the $xy$ plane, but I'm stuck on finding the stabilizer of $(0,0,1)$ in $I^n$. Any hint or solution is very appreciated!
